# how to get the difference between 2 times in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the difference between 2 times where the results I want are not just rounding up or down to the nearest hour but there are half an hour

```
SELECT  (CEILING(ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,
    ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,CURDATE(),'2019-04-16 17:30:00')/60)*60,
    CURDATE()),'2019-04-16 21:00:00')/60,1)/ 0.5) * 0.5)
```

in that query, the result is 3.0 hour but but what i want is 3.5 hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with time handling is not to convert it to a string:

```
SELECT ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2019-04-16 17:30:00','2019-04-16 21:00:00')))/3600
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round to the nearest half hour, just use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` with an argument of minutes, divide by 30 (half an hour) and then `ROUND` to get an exact number of half hour periods, and then divide by 2 to get the number of hours to the nearest half hour:

```
SELECT ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2019-04-16 17:30:00','2019-04-16 21:00:00') / 30) / 2
```

Output

```
3.5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56cfd0a21c21dd2ffa5d38e504152536)